# ZF: what is the point of using the setQuery/setPost methods of Zend_Controller_Request_Http?

Tags: php, zend-framework

Since these methods just set values within the $_GET and $_POST superglobals, can someone tell me what the point of using these methods are as opposed to just setting the values directly?  I feel like I'm missing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best arguments are:

1. Hide the supergloabals so your code will still work if future versions of PHP modify, deprecate, or remove their functionality, as was done with `$HTTP_POST_VARS`, etc.
2. In future versions of Zend Framework, additional functionality may need to be added to the `setQuery()` and `setPost()` functions.